# Append a var to url with jquery function

Tags: jquery, url

I am looking to append a var to a url with a function that i have bounf to a click event.

Say the url is www.example.com

after running the function it becomes.

www.example.com?folder=beats

I have got the function grabbing the right folder value but need to append it to the current page url.

```
function fileDialogStart() {

$folder = $('#ams3Folder').val();



}
```

any help

Comment: The browsers URL or just some string?

Comment: use `var` to declare variables so you do not create an implied global.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function fileDialogStart() 
{
    var newURLString = window.location.href + 
            "?folder=" + $('#ams3Folder').val();

    window.location.href = newURLString;    // The page will redirect instantly 
                                            // after this assignment
}
```

For more information, go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).

Comment: David Walsh has a great page on `window.location` too: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location

Answer (score 3):

```
function fileDialogStart() {

$folder = $('#ams3Folder').val();

window.location.href = window.location.href + $folder

// window.location.href = window.location.href + '?test=10';

}
```

Comment: hi tarek just one problem is if i run it twice i get www.example.com?folder=beats?folder=beats which messes it up????

Comment: you have 2 options : clean up the location.href using replace() before appending variable or do something like :  window.location.href = 'index.php?'+$folder